# spinner dropdown start from top of spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

Problem is `Spinner` dropdown list start from top line of Spinner but it should be start from bottom line of `Spinner`

Normal state

[image]

After Click

[image]

**Spinner xml code**

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spnSelectLanguage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:background="@drawable/spn_lang_dropdown_selector"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:popupBackground="#EAEAEA"
    android:textColor="#54a4db" />
```

**Code**

```
Spinner spnSelectLanguage = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spnSelectLanguage);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLanguage= new ArrayAdapter<String> (context,R.layout.layout_lng_spinner_item,new String[]{"English","Arabic"});
    adapterLanguage.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spnSelectLanguage.setAdapter(adapterLanguage);
```

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@color/grey</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: it's nothing but `drawable selector`. you can put anything as background.

Answer (score 23):

In your spinner:

```
android:overlapAnchor="false"
```

**NOTE** If you are supporting API below 21, this attribute has to be copy and pasted as it is available for API >= 21.

Comment: beautiful! Spent almost 16 hours finding what can be done so that the popup dropdown of `AppCompatSpinner` in my layout does not overlap the spinner view. You Rock! This should be the selected answer. **NOTE** This attribute has to be **copy and pasted** as it is available for `API >= 21`

Answer (score 16):

You can to set this lines in your Spinner xml code:

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
android:dropDownVerticalOffset="50dp"
```

With this, your dropdownview will start with top offset. You can hardcode the offset number or calculate it at runtime and use:

```
setDropDownVerticalOffset(int pixels)
```

More in:
[Android Spinner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)

Answer (score 0):

For me worked only when I created spinner style and added the "android:spinnerStyle" item to style of my theme.

I opened my `/res/values/styles.xml`, found my theme ("AppTheme") and added `<item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/custom_spinner</item>` like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>            
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/custom_spinner</item>
</style>

<style name="custom_spinner" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
</style>
```